# Using java class path properly, clarification needed

Tags: java, linux

I am running the program as:

```
java -Dfirstarg=$1 -cp $APP_HOME/someFile.cfg;$APP_HOME/lib/*.jar ::  Handler
```

With the intention to pass the argument and include someFile.cfg and all jars under `$APP_HOME/lib/` to class path.

What am i doing wrong please?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass the `someFile.cfg` into the class-path. You just need to add the libraries, and current directory there.

I would do:

```
java -Dfirstarg=$1 -cp .:$APP_HOME/lib/*.jar YourMainClass
```

Assuming you are in a directory where your `.class` files are.

**Also, do keep in mind that in linux you use `:` and not `;` to separate your class path entries in the `-cp` arguments.**